# How can I resolve the 'Could not load folder contents' error on Power BI Report Server when users have been granted folder access?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, reportserver

In power BI report server I'm the admin and upload reports on it for client users. I defined them as user in our network. I gave them access to PBI RS folders. Every thing is seems right. They enter the currect credentails and login to RS. But an error pops up:

> Could not load folder contents, you are not allowed to view this
> folder.

But I alredy Gave the access to the folder!!!

How to fix this permission error?